# Load Content in a div with already loaded content and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have like 14 pages e.g page1, page2, page3, page4, page 5, page 6. Now the page 1 is loaded by default through load. And page1 has link to load next page. On page2 it has link to go back to page 1 and move to next page page 4 without refreshing just loading and so on.

So now i need a code for next and previous links for each load also i have a 10th page which have links for all pages that loads and it should be also loaded.
The code i am using for loads. But its only working upto 2 loads. I need to make load through all pages with next and previous links and one loaded page for all links. I have html and css ready need help in js. Thanks

```
 $(function(){
      $('.modal-body').load('pages/page1.html', function(){
        //load your second set of html here with another load.
        $('.changed').click(function(){
             var page = $(".changed").attr('href');
            console.log(page);
            var loaded = $('.modal-body').load('pages/' + page + '.html');
            return false;
          });
    });

    });
```

Every Loaded page have link like

```
<a href="changed">Next</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have already one navigation working outside the loaded content. But i need navigation within every new loaded page as well.

Comment: Should there be `class="changed"` in that link?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `<a class="changed" href="page2">Next</a>`? And each page should have the next pageN in its link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a page counter in the Javascript. And you can use event delegation so you don't need to bind new handlers every time you reload the body.

```
$(function(){
  $('.modal-body').load('pages/page1.html'); // Load page 1 at start
  var curPage = 1;
  $(document).on("click", ".nextpage", function() {
    curPage++;
    $('.modal-body').load('pages/page' + curPage + '.html');
    return false;
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".prevpage", function() {
    curPage--;
    $('.modal-body').load('pages/page' + curPage + '.html');
    return false;
  });
});
```

The HTML should then have:

```
<a class="prevpage" href="#">Previous</a> <a class="nextpage" href="#">Next</a>
```

Comment: Ok thanks let me try it. Also i have one page with all the pages links and its loaded as well through jquery load. Any idea on how to post all links there to load content for each. thanks

Comment: Those can be like you wrote in the question.

Comment: I have added the all pages code but its not working. e,g the all page links code loaded when curPage == 2. Can you please let me know in which function should i add the code for all links. Much Appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be in any function, they should just be static links. But maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do on that page. You should ask a new question for this.